# My async Task always blocks UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, dispatcher, async-await

In a WPF 4.5 application, I don't understand why the UI is blocked when I used await + a task :

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Task.Delay works great
        //await Task.Delay(5000);

        double value = await JobAsync(25.0);

        MessageBox.Show("finished : " + value.ToString());
    }

    private async Task<double> JobAsync(double value)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30000000; i++)
            value += Math.Log(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(value, 0.75)));

        return value;
    }
```

The await Task.Delay works great, but the await JobAsync blocks the UI. Why ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
private Task<double> JobAsync(double value)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30000000; i++)
            value += Math.Log(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(value, 0.75)));

        return value;
    });
}
```

Comment: Rather than starting the task inside of the method it might make more sense to add a `Task.Run` call on the line with `await`, although the end result (if the function is never re-used) is identical.

Comment: Im in a similar scenario, still blocks the UI Thread. Are there any obvious gotchas?

Answer (score 26):

You should be getting a warning about `JobAsync` - it contains no `await` expressions. *All* your work is still being done on the UI thread. There's really nothing asynchronous about the method.

Marking a method as `async` doesn't make it run on a different thread - it's more that it makes it easier to join together asynchronous operations, and come back to the appropriate context.

I suspect it would be a good idea to take a step back and absorb some of the materials about async on MSDN... [this is a good starting point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)...